# If $\alpha$ is a regular cardinal, the union of an elementary chain of $\alpha$-saturated models is also a $\alpha$-saturated model

Tags: model-theory

I'm studying Model Theory with the book of Chang-Keisler, and I'm trying to solve the following problem stated in Chapter 5:

> The union of an elementary chain $(M_i)_{i < \alpha}$ of $\alpha$-saturated models is also $\alpha$-saturated, if $\alpha$ is regular.

I'm considering the following definition:

> $M$ is a $\alpha$-saturated model if for all $A \subset M$, $|A| < \alpha$, every $1$-type $p$ in $A$ over $T(M) = \left \{ \varphi: M \models \varphi \right \}$ is realized in $M$, i.e. there exists $a \in M$ such that $M \models \varphi(a), \, \forall \varphi \in p.$

My attempt:

Let $(M_i)_{i < \alpha}$ be an elementary chain of $\alpha$-saturated models and let $M = \bigcup_{i < \alpha} M_i$. Given $A \subset M$ with $|A| < \alpha$ and $p$ a $1$-type in $A$ over $T(M)$, if I prove that there exists $i < \alpha$ such that $p$ is a type over $T(M_i)$, we could conclude that there exists $a$ in $M_i$, with $M_i \models \varphi(a)$ for all $\varphi \in p$. Hence $a \in M$ and $M \models \varphi(a)$, since $M_i$ is an elementary substructure of $M$.

So, how can I proof the existence of such $i < \alpha$?

Comment: I edited to clean things up a bit. The word is "saturated", not "satured".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows directly from the definition of regular cardinal.

For each $a\in A$, let $i_a$ be the least ordinal such that $a\in M_{i_a}$. Then $I = \{i_a\mid a\in A\}$ is a subset of $\alpha$ of cardinality at most $|A|<\alpha$. By regularity, $I$ is not cofinal in $\alpha$, so $j = \sup I < \alpha$. Thus $A\subseteq M_j$, and $p$ is a type over $M_j$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Each element $a$ of $A$ is in $M_{i(a)}$ for some $i(a)<\alpha$. Since $|A|<\alpha$, there are fewer than $\alpha$ of these $i(a)$'s. By regularity of $\alpha$, there is some $\beta<\alpha$ that is larger than all the $i(a)$'s. So $A\subseteq M_\beta$. As $M_\beta$ is $\alpha$-saturated, $p$ is realized in $M_\beta$ and therefore (since $M_\beta\preceq M$) also realized in $M$.